# How to run a function based on an answer

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out how to make a script to run a function based on an answer provided, at the moment my script creates and populates a word doc with answers provided from a google form. I want to streamline it so that I can use one google form to create different documents based on an answer provided rather than creating multiple google forms. I am very new to JavaScript and I am pretty sure I need an if statement at the beginning of everything, but I don't know what I should write or where it should go. This is my script:

```
function onOpen()  {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs');
  menu.addToUi();

}

function createNewGoogleDocs(){

  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('google file goes here');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('google folder goes here');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Response');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

rows.forEach(function(row,index) {
  if (index === 0) return;
  if (row[9]) return;
  const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[5]} document name goes here`, destinationFolder);
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
  const body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText('{{Name}}', row[5]);
  body.replaceText('{{To}}', row[6]);
  body.replaceText('{{Items}}', row[7]);
  body.replaceText('{{Reasoning}}', row[8])
  body.replaceText('{{Submitter}}', row[1]);
  body.replaceText('{{Role}}', row[2]);
  body.replaceText('{{Time}}', row[3]);
  body.replaceText('{{Discord}}', row[4]);



  doc.saveAndClose();
  const url = doc.getUrl();
  sheet.getRange(index + 1, 10).setValue(url)




})




}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS in a [mcve]. It is not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: I have few questions, 
You want to create new document based on response provided by user through google form?
You have multiple documents template and based on response you want to choose between those template to create final document filled with user response?